# setTimeout loop wait another setTimeout loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, callback, settimeout

I want to execute second function after first function is done.
result: 
   i: 0,i: 1,...,i: 9,

   j: 0,j: 1,...,j: 9

```
function first(callback){
  for(let i = 0 ; i < 10;i++){
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('i: ',i);
    },10*i);
  }
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback();  
  },10*i);
}

function second(){
  for(let j = 0 ; j < 10; j++){
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('j: ',j);
    },10*j);
  }
}

first(second());
```

Comment: you called second first by executing it when you passed it to first, should be `first(second);`, because second is the callback. You big dummy :-)

Comment: @r3wt It's obvious the last part of your comment was meant to be jokingly, but you may want to consider removing it anyways.

Comment: @Azeame nah, i'm good. back in my day, being a noob on this site and asking a dumb question would get you skull dragged by an angry mob. i don't agree with this soft pc culture at all. the abuse i took here made me a tougher person, and also a more conscious software developer in terms of security and ethics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 10 iterations in `first`, so the callback for `second` should run after `10 * 10` milliseconds. Also make sure to *pass* `second` into `first` instead of calling `second` immediately:

```js
function first(callback) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('i: ', i);
    }, 10 * i);
  }
  setTimeout(callback, 10 * 10)
}

function second() {
  for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('j: ', j);
    }, 10 * j);
  }
}

first(second);
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for answer.